# Creating a Slider Shortcode Based on Nivo Slider

Tags: shortcode

I´m new with wordpress and I need to create a slider based on Nivo library. There I would like to create the shortcode using this syntax:

```
[slider]
[image]http: //www .domain.com/images/1.jpg[/image]
[image]http: //www .domain.com/images/2.jpg[/image]
[image]http: //www .domain.com/images/n.jpg[/image]
[/slider]
```

The output code would be like this:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
  <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <img src="image-path.jpg" data-thumb="image-path.jpg" alt="text"/>
    <img src="image-path.jpg.jpg" data-thumb="image-path.jpg" alt="text"/>
    <img src="image-path.jpg" data-thumb="image-path.jpg" alt="text"/>
  </div>
  <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
    <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.
  </div>
</div>
```

I have not so much experience with php either and I tried to do something like this:

```
function nivo_slider_func($atts)
{
  extract(shortcode_atts(array('gallery_name' => ''), $atts));
  $output = "<div class='slider-wrapper theme-default'>";
  $output .= "<div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'>";
  $atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
      'url' => '',
      'title' => ''
    ), $atts);

  foreach ($atts as $atts) {
    $src = $atts['url'];
    $title = $atts['title'];
    $output .= "<img src='" . $src . "' data-thumb='" . $src . "' alt='" . $title . "' />";
  }
  $output .= "</div></div>";
  return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'slider', 'nivo_slider_func' );
```

But it does not work correctly. Could you help me with this, please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

that's will be nested shortcodes, so you will need [slider] and [image] shortcode

```
add_shortcode( 'nivo_slider', 'nivo_slider_func' ); 
function nivo_slider_func( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $output  =  '<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">';
    $output .=  '<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">';
    $output .=  do_shortcode($content);
    $output .=  '</div></div>';
    return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'image', 'nivo_image_shortcode' );
function nivo_image_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'title' => ''
    ), $atts )
    );
    return '<img src="'.$content.'"  data-thumb="'.$content.'" title="'.$atts['title'].'" alt="'.$atts['title'].'" />';
}
```

Comment: Gembel, IT WORKED LIKE A CHARM! Thank you very much!! :)

Comment: Glad it help ;)

Comment: I´m sorry, I´m quite new on stackoverflow and I don´t know well best practices in order to follow correctly threads. My apologizes.

Comment: A last question. The shortcode generates a paragraph element I need to remove, this is the output:

<p><img src="http://path-to-image.jpg"  data-thumb="http://path-to-image.jpg" title="" alt="" /></p>
What should I do to remove that paragraph element from the markup?
 
I tried using: remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 12); But it does not work, paragraphs are in my markup still. 
Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

at first glance i see, you registered `nivo-slider` as your shortcode but you've used `[slider]`. you need to register `slider` as your shortcode.

```
add_shortcode( 'slider', 'nivo_slider_func' );
```

or, if you want to use `nivo-slider` as your shortcode, you will need to update how you used it. in that case you don't need the above code.

```
[nivo-slider] [image]http: //www .domain.com/images/1.jpg[/image] [image]http: //www .domain.com/images/2.jpg[/image] [image]http: //www .domain.com/images/n.jpg[/image] [/nivo-slider]
```

but it's better if you do not use hyphen as it may cause problems occasionally:
 http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Hyphens

Comment: *Off-topic* : HungryCoder, when you edit a question, take a look if the title and the content can be upgraded too. A good title for this question would've been: "Creating a Slider Shortcode Based on Nivo Slider". And the two last sentences could've been removed: "Could you help..." and "Thanks...". Regards!

Comment: I have updated title and corrected the code. Initially the [slider] was just the example. What I need to do is get the [images] and pass them to the slider. How can I catch them?

Comment: in that case your scenario explanation was wrong. however, for nested shortcode, you can follow what Gembel Intelek suggested. You can read here too: http://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-nested-shortcodes/